# Closing the webdriver instance automatically after the test failed

Tags: python, testing, selenium, python-unittest

My English is very poor but I'll try my best to describe the problem I encountered.

I used selenium webdriver to test a web site and the language that I used to write my script is python.Because of this,I used Pyunit.

I know that if my test suite have no exceptions,the webdriver instance will be closed correctly,(by the way, I used chrome) however,once a exception was threw,the script will be shut down and I have to close chrome manually.

I wonder that how can I achieved that when a python process quits , any remaining open WebDriver instances will also be closed.

By the way, I used Page Object Design Pattern,and the code below is a part of my script:

```
class personalcenter(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.page = personalCenter(self.driver,"admin","123456")

    def testAddWorkExp(self):

        blahblahblah...

    def tearDown(self):

        self.page.quit()
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    unittest.main()
```

I haved searched the solution of this problem for a long time ,but almost every answer is depended on java and junit or testNG.How can I deal with this issue with Pyunit?

Thanks for every answer.

Comment: self.page.quit() in the teardown function just means to logout from the website,it doesn't means to close chrome,next command do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`tearDown()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown) documentation:

> Method called immediately after the test method has been called and
>   the result recorded. This is called even if the test method raised an
>   exception, so the implementation in subclasses may need to be
>   particularly careful about checking internal state. Any exception
>   raised by this method will be considered an error rather than a test
>   failure. **This method will only be called if the `setUp()` succeeds**,
>   regardless of the outcome of the test method. The default
>   implementation does nothing.

So, the only case where `tearDown` will not be called is when `setUp` fails.
Therefore I would simply catch the exception inside setUp, close the driver, and re-raise it:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        self.page = personalCenter(self.driver,"admin","123456")
    except Exception:
        self.driver.quit()
        raise
```

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved the problem, please mark the answer as accepted so that others can also refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Hope!! this will help you. you might need to close the driver with boolean expression as False

from selenium import webdriver

import time

class Firefoxweb(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    print("this is to run the test")

def seltest(self):

    driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\Drivers\chromedriver.exe")

    driver.get("URL")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btnSkip']").click()

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='userInput']").send_keys("ABC")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='passwordInput']").send_keys("*******")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='BtnLogin']").click()
    driver.close(False)
```

FF=Firefoxweb()
FF.seltest()